# INDEX and AGGREGATE FUNCTION in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, aggregate-functions, multi-index

I have a two tables are data and report.

In data table the following columns are Size A, Size B and Size C, Type and Rank.

In data table I created rank for each type based on the sizes. The purpose of the rank column were multiple matches for same size in this case the rank column will help to decide exact type were match more than one.

In report table the following columns are Size A, Size B and Size C.

In both table the Size A, Size B and Size C columns are common/relationship.

I am trying find out the appropriate type according to the Size A, Size B and Size C from data table into report table.

**Data:**

| TYPE | SIZEA | SIZEB | SIZEC | RANK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A6 | 420 | 600 | 440 | 11.00 |
| A4 | 640 | 600 | 480 | 9.00 |
| A5 | 890 | 1100 | 1330 | 2.00 |
| A6 | 1335 | 1100 | 2350 | 1.00 |
| A7 | 890 | 1100 | 390 | 5.00 |
| A8 | 890 | 1100 | 530 | 3.00 |
| A9 | 670 | 1100 | 540 | 4.00 |
| A10 | 670 | 1100 | 440 | 6.00 |
| A11 | 320 | 1100 | 440 | 10.00 |
| A12 | 600 | 400 | 400 | 12.00 |
| A13 | 800 | 600 | 400 | 8.00 |
| A14 | 1000 | 600 | 500 | 7.00 |

**Report:**

| SIZEA | SIZEB | SIZEC | DESIRED RESULT-TYPE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 400 | 300 | 140 | A12 |
|  |  |  | A12 |
| 250 | 250 | 160 | A12 |
| 600 | 400 | 285 | A12 |
| 400 | 300 | 150 | A12 |
| 280 | 230 | 170 | A12 |
| 320 | 320 | 320 | A12 |
| 320 | 320 | 320 | A12 |
| 600 | 400 | 140 | A12 |
| 400 | 300 | 140 | A12 |
| 400 | 300 | 140 | A12 |
| 370 | 320 | 340 | A12 |
| 320 | 240 | 250 | A12 |
| 300 | 200 | 90 | A12 |
| 400 | 290 | 140 | A12 |

I am applying following formula in report table in order to get the appropriate type according to the Size A, Size B and Size C

```
=INDEX(DATA!$D$2:$D$16,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW(DATA!$H$2:$H$16)-1)/(DATA!$H$2:$H$16=1/(1/MAX(((DATA!$E$2:$E$16>=$B3)*(DATA!$F$2:$F$16>=$A3)+(DATA!$E$2:$E$16>=$A3)*(DATA!$F$2:$F$16>=$B3)>0)*(DATA!$G$2:$G$16>=$C3)*DATA!$H$2:$H$16))),1))
```

[image]

[image]

How can I apply the same logic in Power BI? Any advise please.

I am looking for new calculate column options. Herewith share the Excel file for your reference

https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/iq0gteeyazrg79q7a4tb1/AUTO-MODIFY-REQ.xlsx?dl=0&rlkey=nyyerjsg7if2dz30z9iqo6kdc

Comment: You need the `ranking ` or the `type`? It seem like the very long formula only return `A12` at the end, is there any mistake?

Comment: I am looking for type not rank.

Comment: ok, let me see if I can understand your formula first.

Comment: I used rank column in order to get the apporiate type according sizes in both tables. Example - If we looking for type In report table for 1 st row size will fit from A4 to A14 in this case we have to choose appropriate type according to the Size. That's the reason I am using rank column.

Comment: Thanks for your support and help. This is very complex scenario

Comment: I understand how your formula work now, but i think it may need both `looping` and `list` in power query, it is beyond my knowledge to solve it, sorry about that.

Comment: Thanks for your time to investigate and understand my query and formula. I thought in power BI easy to resolve it but sounds like more complex. I am happy to maintain lot additional/duplicate columns in both tables in order to achieve my desired result but again not sure it possible in Power BI. I am trying to find out more simple formula in Excel and update here could you please have a and advice.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233703/discussion-between-johon-and-kin-siang).

Comment: Hmm, nothing I can do for PowerBI in your case, do you need something else?

Comment: Thank you. If you don't mind can you please provide excel file so I can use it in future.

Comment: Hmm, i already delete the excel already, and won't remake it, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another formula that will return the same result as per your current formula, although it is still a long formula, but more easily to understand:

```
=INDEX($D$2:$D$13,MATCH(MAX(IF($G$2:$G$13<$L3,0,
IF((IF($E$2:$E$13<$K3,0,1)*IF($F$2:$F$13<$J3,0,1))+(IF($E$2:$E$13<$J3,0,1)*IF($F$2:$F$13<$K3,0,1))>0,1,0))
*$H$2:$H$13),$H$2:$H$13,0),1)
```

[image]

So I will break it down to explain how do it working:

**Part 1**: This if formula is checking comparison of `Size C`, if your data is lower than than table, the value for the `Type` will be zero therefore will not be considered at all because `zero times any amount` will be zero

```
(IF($G$2:$G$13<$L3,0
```

**Part 2**: This part is will first checking comparison of `Size A vs Size B`, if lower than table than return 0 and apply for other comparison, at then end using `If at the beginning` to `reset` the value so than the final value will be 0 or 1

```
IF((IF($E$2:$E$13<$K3,0,1)*IF($F$2:$F$13<$J3,0,1))+(IF($E$2:$E$13<$J3,0,1)*IF($F$2:$F$13<$K3,0,1))>0,1,0)
```

**Part 3**: From the value you calculate, if 0 times any ranking will be zero, so from none zero ranking such as 12 or 9, it will get the max value from the list, most of them are `12`

```
Max((.....)*$H$2:$H$13)
```

**Part 4**: Index Match - Finally it is same as your formula first part, but you are using `Index row` which make it difficult to understand

```
INDEX($D$2:$D$13,MATCH(Max(...))
```

A shorter version of your formula by removing unnecessary portion:

```
=INDEX($D$2:$D$13,MATCH(MAX(IF($G$2:$G$13<$L4,0,
IF(($E$2:$E$13>=$K4)*($F$2:$F$13>=$J4)+($E$2:$E$13>=$J4)*($F$2:$F$13>=$K4)>0,1,0))*$H$2:$H$13),
$H$2:$H$13,0),1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a colum to your report table like:

```
Desired = LOOKUPVALUE(DataR[TYPE],DataR[RANK], MAXX(FILTER(DataR, DataR[SIZEA] >= ReportR[SIZEA] && DataR[SIZEB] >= ReportR[SIZEB] && DataR[SIZEC] >= ReportR[SIZEC]), DataR[RANK]))
```

It first filters the table to find the row where the sizes are more or equal to the report row, selects the rank and then does a lookup to the type.

Result:
[image]

Comment: No, your result is incorrect, actually the problem is that some of the type is `A6`, i think quite close already, although not sure can solve in BI easily?

Comment: Hi. Thank you so much for your help and providing solutions as well. The formula result(your solution) almost matched according to Excel formula results, some of them different type and some of them blanks according to desired result. The reason is different because I used rotate option in Excel formula. In data table Type A can go into report table Type B and in data table Type B can go into report table A.

Comment: Good morning. Can you please advise is possible add one more logic in your exciting.

Comment: I have been busy cannot promise you when i have time to look into this..

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I can wait until your respond again. Can you please help me when you have time. Thank you.

Comment: You are saying there is difference, can you be more explicit on what is different so I know how to translate this into logic?